# which is better to use and why? abstractapplication context or applicationcontext

Tags: spring

I tried `ApplicationContext` and `AbstractApplicationContext` both are working fine.
Whether the only difference between those two is `registershutdownhook` method calling or anything else. Want to know which is better

Answer (score 1):

**AbstractApplicationContext** [Reference Link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html)

> Abstract implementation of the ApplicationContext interface. Doesn't
>   mandate the type of storage used for configuration; simply implements
>   common context functionality. Uses the Template Method design pattern,
>   requiring concrete subclasses to implement abstract methods. In
>   contrast to a plain BeanFactory, an ApplicationContext is supposed to
>   detect special beans defined in its internal bean factory: Therefore,
>   this class automatically registers BeanFactoryPostProcessors,
>   BeanPostProcessors and ApplicationListeners which are defined as beans
>   in the context.
>
> A MessageSource may also be supplied as a bean in the context, with
>   the name "messageSource"; otherwise, message resolution is delegated
>   to the parent context. Furthermore, a multicaster for application
>   events can be supplied as "applicationEventMulticaster" bean of type
>   ApplicationEventMulticaster in the context; otherwise, a default
>   multicaster of type SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster will be used.
>
> Implements resource loading through extending DefaultResourceLoader.
>   Consequently treats non-URL resource paths as class path resources
>   (supporting full class path resource names that include the package
>   path, e.g. "mypackage/myresource.dat"), unless the
>   DefaultResourceLoader.getResourceByPath(java.lang.String) method is
>   overwritten in a subclass.

**ApplicationContext** [Reference Link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html)

> Central interface to provide configuration for an application. This is
>   read-only while the application is running, but may be reloaded if the
>   implementation supports this. An ApplicationContext provides:
>
> Bean factory methods for accessing application components. Inherited
>   from ListableBeanFactory. The ability to load file resources in a
>   generic fashion. Inherited from the ResourceLoader interface. The
>   ability to publish events to registered listeners. Inherited from the
>   ApplicationEventPublisher interface. The ability to resolve messages,
>   supporting internationalization. Inherited from the MessageSource
>   interface. Inheritance from a parent context. Definitions in a
>   descendant context will always take priority. This means, for example,
>   that a single parent context can be used by an entire web application,
>   while each servlet has its own child context that is independent of
>   that of any other servlet. In addition to standard BeanFactory
>   lifecycle capabilities, ApplicationContext implementations detect and
>   invoke ApplicationContextAware beans as well as ResourceLoaderAware,
>   ApplicationEventPublisherAware and MessageSourceAware beans.

**Structure**

`public abstract class AbstractApplicationContext extends DefaultResourceLoader implements ConfigurableApplicationContext, DisposableBean`

`public interface ConfigurableApplicationContext extends ApplicationContext`

`public interface ApplicationContext extends EnvironmentCapable, ListableBeanFactory, HierarchicalBeanFactory,MessageSource, ApplicationEventPublisher, ResourcePatternResolver`

ConfigurableApplicationContext declare this signature

```
/**
 * Register a shutdown hook with the JVM runtime, closing this context
 * on JVM shutdown unless it has already been closed at that time.
 * <p>This method can be called multiple times. Only one shutdown hook
 * (at max) will be registered for each context instance.
 * @see java.lang.Runtime#addShutdownHook
 * @see #close()
 */
void registerShutdownHook();
```

In summary i suggest to use the AbstractApplicationContext only if you want really get profit of the above features else, is better to use ApplicationContext.